# Chrome extension that parses certain text from xml

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extensions that opens xml of a website, but I need it to parse certain text from that XML that has value set to "1". I tried using xPath, but couldn't get the hang of it.   Example here:

```
<option value="1">
  <text>
     <![CDATA[
      NEED THIS PARSED
      ]]>
  </text>
<feedback/>
</option>
<option value="0">
  <text>
    <![CDATA[ DONT NEED THIS PARSED ]]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning it into a document with DOMParser allows you to use methods like `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, which might be easier:

```js
const text = `<option value="1">
  <text>
     <![CDATA[
      NEED THIS PARSED
      ]]>
  </text>
<feedback/>
</option>
<option value="0">
  <text>
    <![CDATA[ DONT NEED THIS PARSED ]]>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/xml');
const textElm = doc.querySelector('option[value="1"] text');
const content = textElm.textContent;
console.log(content);
```

The query string

```
option[value="1"] text
```

means: select a `text` element which is a descendant of an `option` element which has a `value` attribute of `1`.